# VBA Find NAMED column and filter - Nearly working macro

Tags: excel, vba

I am struggling to cover everything I need to do in one macro - I asked a similar question here a few hours ago and was answered however unfortunately I needed to add a few functions to my macro so I had to modify it slightly and now I require a tiny tweak that I can't get to work

```
Sub BoBTEST()
Dim c As Range

    For Each c In Range("A1:BR1").Cells
        If c.Value = "Plate Name (barcode)" Or c.Value = "Measurement Date" Or c.Value = "Measurement profile" Or c.Value = "pH" Or c.Value = "Count" Or c.Value <= 30 Then
            c.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        Else: c.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        End If
        Next c
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range( _
        "AF2:AF1761"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range( _
        "AN2:AN1761"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range( _
        "J2:J1761"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:BR1761")
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

    Range("A1:BR1761").Select
    Range("AT9").Activate
    Selection.AutoFilter
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$BR$1761").AutoFilter Field:=32, Criteria1:= _
        "=Shear Rated(gamma)/dt = 4 1/s", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="="
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$BR$1761").AutoFilter Field:=40, Criteria1:= _
        "=Viscosity", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="="
End Sub
```

Basically what it does so far is takes data which is exported from a robot, hides the columns that I don't want and filters the values that I don't want

The problem is that these columns are dynamic and occasionally move around - the macro is able to hide all of the columns I don't want however I'm struggling to make it search for these columns and then filter, right now it is using a recording I did so it selects e.g. column J and then filters

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range( _
    "J2:J1761"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortNormal
```

However it may not be on column J it might be at K as occasionally more columns are entered when exporting data

Is there any way to tweak the macro to make it so the auto-filter part actually searches for column headers as opposed to doing these functions on e.g. "J2:J2000" etc.

Thanks a lot apologies that it is long winded I wanted to cover everything

Comment: You can use Cells instead of Range then find the column number for the header of the column you want to hide

Comment: Look at using something like `worksheetfunction.match()` and then `offset` so for example if "Test" was in J, then `worksheetfunction.match("Test","1:1",false)` would return 10, then you could set your filter to be `range("a1:a2000").offset(0,10)`

Comment: Hi Fernando and Nathan thanks for the reply there's just a couple of points im not sure about
If using cells instead of range would i be able to incorporate a search for the column header as the column may move on different exports - so for example would i be able to search row 1:1 for the header i need and then sort it?

Secondly i looked into worksheetfunction.match() and it seems like a good option but im not sure what is meant by
worksheetfunction.match("Test","1:1",false) would return 10 - i need it to match a named column header and then sort if pos,
Thanks a lot for the responses !